# Not able to output object in linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, operator-overloading

I have created a linked list and in each list consists a node that holds a CarPart object. I believe I have everything working, except outputting the cout. I get the following errors

`'CarPart::getPartNumber': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member (carpart.cpp  line 34)`

`'CarPart::getDescription': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member  (carpart.cpp line 35)`

`'CarPart::getPrice': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member    (carpart.cpp line 36)`

I have tried changing the osstream operator and have not been able to figure out the issue.

Main.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "List.h"



int main()
{

    List partsList;

    partsList.push_front(new CarPart("FL2016", "Oil Filter", 18.95));
    partsList.push_front(new CarPart("RS12YC", "Spark Plug", 4.15));
    partsList.push_front(new CarPart("D5941", "Digital Tire Guage", 12.15));
    partsList.push_back(new CarPart("G19216", "Car Wash Solution", 8.15));

    partsList.display();
    cout << "now we are going to remove the first item in the list" << endl;
    system("PAUSE");

    partsList.pop_front();

    partsList.display();

    system("PAUSE");
    cout << "now we are going to remove the LAST item from the list" << endl;

    partsList.pop_back();

    partsList.display();

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

List.h

```
#pragma once
#include "node.h"
class List
{

private:
    int listSize;
    Node* n;
    Node* temp;
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;

public:
    List();
    void push_front(CarPart*);
    void push_back(CarPart*);
    void pop_front();
    void pop_back();
    void display();

    ~List();
};
```

List.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "List.h"


List::List()
{
}

void List::push_front(CarPart* dat)
{
    if (listSize == 0) {

        n = new Node;
        n->setData(dat);
        listSize++;
        temp = n;
        head = n;
        tail = n;

    }
    else {

        n = new Node;
        n->setData(dat);
        listSize++;
        temp = head;
        head = n;
        n->setNext(temp);
        n->setPrevious(nullptr);
        temp->setPrevious(n);
        temp = n;
    }

}

void List::push_back(CarPart* dat)
{
    if (listSize == 0) {

        n = new Node;
        n->setData(dat);
        listSize++;
        temp = n;
        head = n;
        tail = n;
    }
    else {

        n = new Node;
        n->setData(dat);
        listSize++;

        temp = tail;
        temp->setNext(n);
        n->setPrevious(temp);
// SET NEXT TO NULL
        temp = n;
        tail = temp;
    }
}

void List::pop_front()
{
    temp = head->getNext();
    delete head;
    head = temp;
    listSize--;

}

void List::pop_back()
{
    temp = tail->getPrevious();
    delete tail;
    tail = temp;
    tail->setNext(nullptr);
    listSize--;

}

void List::display()
{

    Node* test = head;
    for (int i = 0; i < listSize; i++) {
        cout << test;
    }

}


List::~List()
{
}
```

Node.h

```
#pragma once
#include "CarPart.h"
class Node
{
private:
    CarPart* data;
    Node* next;
    Node* previous;

public:
    Node();
    CarPart* getData();
    void setData(CarPart*);
    void setNext(Node*);
    void setPrevious(Node*);
    Node* getPrevious();
    Node* getNext();
    void display();
    ~Node();
};
```

Node.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Node.h"


Node::Node()
{
}

CarPart* Node::getData()
{
    return data;
}

void Node::setData(CarPart* dat)
{
    data = dat;
}

void Node::setNext(Node* nextNode)
{
    next = nextNode;
}

void Node::setPrevious(Node* prev)
{
    previous = prev;
}

Node * Node::getPrevious()
{
    return previous;
}

Node * Node::getNext()
{
    return next;
}

void Node::display()
{
    cout << data;
}

Node::~Node()
{
}
```

CarPart.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class CarPart
{

private:
    string partNumber;
    string description;
    double price;
public:
    CarPart();
    CarPart(string, string, double);
    string getPartNumber();
    string getDescription();
    double getPrice();
    ~CarPart();
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, CarPart* dt);
};
```

CarPart.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CarPart.h"


CarPart::CarPart()
{
}

CarPart::CarPart(string n, string d, double p)
{
    partNumber = n;
    description = d;
    price = p;
}

string CarPart::getPartNumber()
{
    return partNumber;
}

string CarPart::getDescription()
{
    return description;
}

double CarPart::getPrice()
{
    return price;
}


ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, CarPart* dt)
{
    os << dt->getPartNumber;
    os << dt->getDescription;
    os << dt->getPrice;
    return os;
}


CarPart::~CarPart()
{
}
```

### Update

I fixed the error below, but it is not outputting the car parts, the console just shows 00820788008207880082078800820788. I assume it is just the pointer, but not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling your get functions incorrectly. You are using  `dt->getPartNumber;`  instead of using  `dt->getPartNumber();`

Comment: I updated to ave (), and not it just outputs numbers... obviously is not getting all the way down to the CarPart items. Output is 00820788008207880082078800820788 ... I assume it is just the pointer... but not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I would investigate your display function in Node as you appear to be printing "data" without dereferencing it first

Answer (score 0):

To call a method/function, you always put brackets, even if there is no arguments (`dt->getPartNumber()`). This line

```
os << dt->getPartNumber()
```

means "pass to os the value returned by calling `getPartNumber`".

Otherwise, it interprets `dt->getPartNumber` as a *pointer to the `getPartNumber` function*, which is a very different beast.

NOTE: For future questions, try to post only the minimum code that causes the error instead of the entire program, and try to mark the line where the error is raised. Google for SSCCE.

Comment: LOL I used to post what I thought was relevant, and everyone would ask for all the code... Although it may have been missing something I should have included.

Comment: I updated to ave (), and not it just outputs numbers... obviously is not getting all the way down to the CarPart items. Output is 00820788008207880082078800820788 ... I assume it is just the pointer... but not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: The idea is that you strip parts of your program until you get the bare minimum that still causes you the same error. In that case is a compilation error in a file without dependences, the only needed files are the `CarPart.cpp` and `.h`. If you had dependences, you try to strip them off and see if there is an error.

Comment: Try to debug incrementally. Do `os << new PartCart("Hello", "World", 99.00);`. If that works, the issue probably is with list handling and not `PartCart`. Rinse and repeat. Lots of times.

Comment: Also, do not change the question. The issue you asked has been solved, mark one of the answers as correct. Post further issues as new questions (after you have researched them well enough to write a comprehensive question). This is not a code writting/debugging service.